# how to update events using Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

hiii i am new in rails i have a model called events and i have things like todays event ,past events and upcoming events. I am showing the count of my respective event on index page, i want to update the count using ajax so that my page will not flicker.

my code for controller is:

```
def index
  case params[:view]
  when 'past'
    @events  = Event.find (:all, :conditions => ['start_date < ?', current_date], :order => 'start_date')
  when 'today'
    @events = Event.find (:all, :conditions => ['(start_date  = current_date)'], :order => 'start_date ')
  when 'upcoming'
    @events  = Event.find( :all, :conditions => ['start_date > ?', current_date], :order => 'start_date')
  else
    @events = Event.all
  end
end
```

and code for view is:

```
%li
    - if params[:controller] == "brands"
      %a.tt-top-center{:title => "Total approvals pending"}#{Brand.all.size} 
      %span Past Brands   
    - elsif params[:controller] == "events"
      %a.tt-top-center{:title => "upcoming Events", :href => events_path(:view => "upcoming") }#{Event.count_upcoming}
      %span Upcoming Events



  %li
    - if params[:controller] == "brands"
      %a.tt-top-center{:title => "Total approvals pending"}#{Brand.all.size} 
      %span New Brand
     - elsif params[:controller] == "events"
      %a.blue.tt-top-center{:title => "past Events", :href => events_path(:view => "past")  }#{Event.count_past}
      %span Past Events Blockquote
```

here my count function is able to show the count of events of today,past and upcoming, but i want to update using ajax. Experts please help

Answer (score 1):

First define your code in partial which you want to update and call this method on javascript click event.

supose your partial name is _update_events.html.erb

```
   <div id ="left"><%=render :partial => "update_event"%></div>


      function remove_im_address(id) {


        var container = $("#left");
         $.ajax({
           url: '/your controller/action',
           type: 'get',
           dataType: 'html',
           processData: false,
           success: function(data) {
            container.html(data);

         }
      });
   }
```

in your controller

```
 def action
    #your logic

    render :partial => "events/update_event" ,:layout => false
 end
```

events are your directory in which you put partial.

And in this way you can update specific div of page only and enjoy.........

Comment: hey kasif i am trying this from three days but not getting the exact way to do so can u please tell me in descriptive way. I am not getting what is function remove_im_address(id),container.html(data);

Comment: hii!!I have asked this question months back and resolved this but forgot to update it here..Thanks kasif for your help but I solved it in a different way.Find my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a `index.js.haml` file and added the following line there:

```
$("event").update("#{escape_javascript(render(@event))}");
```

It's working for me.